# PHP Create and delete cookies using query strings

Tags: php

I have the following two links:

```
<a href="index.php?showDesktop=true">Show Desktop</a>

<a href="index.php?showMobile=true">Show Mobile</a>
```

What I want to do is make it so that if the showDesktop query is clicked then create a cookie called showDesktop and delete the cookie showMobile and the vice-versa. I have tried the following so far, but think I'm doing it wrong. Can anyone help me get this working as proposed.

```
if($_GET['showDesktop']) {
    $_COOKIE('showDesktop', 'yes');
    $_COOKIE('showMobile', null);
}
else if($_GET['showMobile']) {
    $_COOKIE('showDesktop', null);
    $_COOKIE('showMobile', 'yes');
}
```

Comment: `$_COOKIE` is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

You use [setcookie](http://php.net/setcookie) to change cookie data:

```
setcookie('showDesktop', 'yes', time()+86400*365);
setcookie('showMobile', false);
```

I do, however, think it's strange to use two different names on the cookie for this. Consider having one called `displayMode` or similar:

```
setcookie('displayMode', 'desktop', time()+86400*365);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its better when you use "true" and "false" instead.

```
if($_GET['showDesktop'] == 'true') {
    setcookie('showDesktop', true);
    setcookie('showMobile', false);
}
else if($_GET['showMobile'] == 'true') {
    setcookie('showDesktop', false);
    setcookie('showMobile', true);
}
```

When you work with cookies its a bit different as **$_GET** and **$_POST**. You should use the function [**setcookie**](http://php.net/manual/de/function.setcookie.php)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need two cookies? Why can't you use the code bellow and parse just one cookie?

```
if($_GET['showDesktop']) {
    $_COOKIE('showDesktop', 'yes');
}
else if($_GET['showMobile']) {
    $_COOKIE('showDesktop', 'no');
}
```

you can also delete cookies by expiring them

```
setcookie ("showDesktop", "", time() - 3600);
```